# Who will be the first person(s) who enter the paradise?

Tags: jannah

As an Islamic rule, good Muslims or Mo'menin (God willing all Muslims) will enter the Jannah after Qiamah (Judgment Day). I was wondering who are going to be considered as the first persons who will enter the Jannah (paradise) after the Day of Judgment?

**Note**: Both Shia and Sunni's view would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If you are asking about the first person, including the prophets and the messengers (PBUT), **then our beloved Prophet Muhammad (PBUH) is the first one to enter paradise. (Sunni's view)**

> Anas b. Malik reported: The Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) said: I will come
>   to the gate of Paradise on the Day of Resurrection. and would seek its
>   opening. and the keeper would say: Who art thou? I would say:
>   Muhammad. He would then say: It is for thee that I have been ordered,
>   and not to open it for anyone before thee.

Answer (score 2):

### Who will be the first person(s) who enter the paradise?

---

There are several similar related --Islamic-- narrations, such as:

> أنّ الخمسة أصحاب الكساء أوّل من يدخل الجنّة، و ذلك أنّ رسول اللّه يدخل
>   الجنّة و عليّ عليه السّلام يحمل لواءه إلى الجنّة، و فاطمة و الحسن و
>   الحسين معهما، و الشيعة  من ورائهم
>
> ...

**Namely (in short):**

**Fives (five persons) of Ksa (کساء) are the first one(s) who enter the Jannah, namely: Prophet Muhammad (pbuh), Ali (a.s.), Fatimah (s.a.), Hassan (a.s. ) and Hussain (a.s.), and the Shia behind them ...**

---

For extra study, for instance (but in Arabic):

> لقد صحت الروايات من طرق الفريقين، أنّ رسول اللّه صلّى اللّه عليه و آله
>   أوّل من يدخل الجنّة قبل الأنبياء، و صحّت أيضا أنّ عليّا أوّل من يدخل
>   الجنّة، و صحّت أيضا أنّ فاطمة أوّل من يدخل الجنّة، و صحّت أيضا أنّ
>   الخمسة أصحاب الكساء أوّل من يدخل الجنّة، و ذلك أنّ رسول اللّه يدخل
>   الجنّة و عليّ عليه السّلام يحمل لواءه إلى الجنّة، و فاطمة و الحسن و
>   الحسين معهما، و الشيعة من ورائهم، و بذلك تلتئم الروايات من حيث المعنى؛
>   فإنّ عليّا و فاطمة و الحسنين يدخلون تحت ظل رسول اللّه و بين يديه؛ فهم
>   أوّل من يدخل الجنّة. ففي أمالي الطوسي (350، 351) بإسناده عن زيد بن
>   عليّ، عن أبيه، عن جدّه، عن عليّ بن أبي طالب عليهم السّلام، عن النبي
>   صلّى اللّه عليه و آله، ... قال له: أنا أوّل من يدخل الجنّة و أنت بعدي
>   تدخلها، و الحسن و الحسين و فاطمة. و في مناقب ابن شهرآشوب (ج 3؛ 229)
>   بالإسناد عن جابر بن عبد اللّه، قال: سمعت رسول اللّه صلّى اللّه عليه و
>   آله يقول: أوّل من يدخل الجنّة بين يدي النبيّين و الصدّيقين عليّ بن أبي
>   طالب، ...
>
> و في ينابيع المودّة (ج 2؛ 94) عن عليّ عليه السّلام قال: شكوت إلى رسول
>   اللّه صلّى اللّه عليه و آله حسد الناس، فقال لي: أ ما ترضى أن تكون رابع
>   أربعة أوّل من يدخل الجنّة؟ أنا و أنت و الحسن و الحسين و أزواجنا عن
>   أيماننا و شمائلنا، و ذريّاتنا خلف أزواجنا. أخرجه الثعلبي، و أخرجه أحمد
>   في المناقب، و ذكره سبط ابن الجوزيّ.
>
> .........
>   (To read the complete text refer to: [www.askdin.com](http://www.askdin.com/showthread.php?t=43405))

---

In the meanwhile, there are many other similar hadiths  (narrations) where mention/name of five individuals "Prophet-Muhammad/Ali/Fatimah/Hassan/Hussain (peace be upon them)" as the first person(s) who enter the paradise(Jannah), hence I recommend you to survey the presented sources below for further info.

---

**Source (as several related sources and more study):**

- [www.askdin.com](http://www.askdin.com/showthread.php?t=43405)
- انظر روضة الواعظين (112، 158) و مناقب ابن شهرآشوب (ج 2؛ 154) و (ج 3؛
  65) و كشف اليقين (108، 281) و أمالي المفيد (74، 110) و المسترشد (634)
- و تفسير فرات (269، 438، 456، 457) و أمالي الصدوق (86، 231، 262) و
  بشارة المصطفى (46، 126) و الخصال (254، 403، 413، 414، 574، 575) و
  الكافي (ج 2؛ 11)، و تقريب المعارف (183) و أمالي الطوسي (351)
- و خصائص الوحي المبين (84). طرف من الأنباء و المناقب، ص: 285 و انظر
  مستدرك الحاكم (ج 3؛ 151) و الكشّاف (ج 4؛ 220) و كنز العمال (ج 6؛ 218)
- و (ج 13؛ 639) و تاريخ دمشق (ج 4؛ 318) و مجمع الزوائد (ج 9؛ 131) و
  كنوز الحقائق بهامش الجامع الصغير (ج 2؛ 16) و الصواعق المحرقة (96) و
  تاريخ بغداد (ج 4؛ 318) و تذكرة الخواص (31) و المختار من مسند فاطمة
  (147)
- و ينابيع المودّة (ج 1؛ 130) و (ج 2؛ 17، 34، 84، 93، 117، 124، 126،
  133) و (ج 3؛ 98) و مناقب الخوارزمي (227). انظر فضائل الخمسة (ج 3؛
  133).
- https://hawzah.net/fa/Book/View/45287/27332/

Comment: Salam dear akhi; thanks for your opinion, but, logically everyone think he/she assume true! (and considers other's as false...! Meanwhile, e.g. AFAIK, there are even Sunni sources which name Hazrat Fatimah as the first one who enters the heaven, too. And so forth....

Comment: Meanwhile, I added related Sunni sources, too.

Answer (score 1):

All praise to Allah (Swt) and blessings on Prophet Muhammad peace be upon him His family and companions.

Narrated AbuHurayrah:
**The Prophet (ﷺ) said: Gabriel came and taking me by the hand showed the gate of Paradise by which my people will enter. AbuBakr then said: Messenger of Allah! I wish I had been with you so that I might have looked at it. The Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) then said: You, AbuBakr, will be the first of my people to enter Paradise.**( Sunan Abi Dawud)

So Prophet Muhammad peace be upon him said that his Close Companion and the First Caliph Abu Bakr r.a would be the first one to enter Paradise.Well we believe that he would be the first person from his Ummah and Prophet Muhammad peace be upon him would be the first from Mankind.

There is one more Hadith

Narrated Sahl bin Sa`d:
**The Prophet (ﷺ) said, "Verily! 70,000 or 700,000 of my followers will enter Paradise altogether; so that the first and the last amongst them will enter at the same time, and their faces will be glittering like the bright full moon."**(Bukhari)

Answer (score -1):

I think our beloved prophet will be th first one. He was forgiven his coming sins and his previous sins by Allah yet he has'nt ever commited a sin