# Who will be last person entering paradise?

Tags: jannah, deeds

Who will be last person entering jannah (paradise) ? And what will be bad deeds of that person?

Comment: Why do you expect both of these would be known?

Comment: @Medi1Saif because first person to enter jannah will be [prohhet Muhammed](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/27802/who-will-be-the-first-persons-who-enter-the-paradise) P.B.U.H and his deeds were best to follow.

Comment: This sounds like an assumption that there's some information, else your statement isn't by default implying this to be true.

Comment: @Medi1Saif https://www.islamreligion.com/articles/10346/last-person-to-enter-paradise-part-1/

Comment: From the link you provided, it looks like you found out the answer to your question. You can post it as an answer then.

Answer (score 1):

As Narrated by `Abdullah:

> The Prophet (ﷺ) said, "I know the person who will be the last to come
>   out of the (Hell) Fire, and the last to enter Paradise. He will be a
>   man who will come out of the (Hell) Fire crawling, and Allah will say
>   to him, 'Go and enter Paradise.' He will go to it, but he will imagine
>   that it had been filled, and then he will return and say, 'O Lord, I
>   have found it full.' Allah will say, 'Go and enter Paradise, and you
>   will have what equals the world and ten times as much (or, you will
>   have as much as ten times the like of the world).' On that, the man
>   will say, 'Do you mock at me (or laugh at me) though You are the
>   King?" I saw Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) (while saying that) smiling that
>   his premolar teeth became visible. It is said that will be the lowest
>   in degree amongst the people of Paradise.

**Sahih Al-Bukhari**

Reference: 6571

Grade: **Sahih**

Comment: Please consider taking your time to elaborate an answer of your own an evidence isn't self explanatory (http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/questions/1475/do-evidences-speak-for-themselves), (read [answer]).

Comment: I don't know what is the problem in providing a hadith as an answer?

Comment: You could explain a bit more!

Comment: Explains what ? 

Quran and Hadith are the most trusted answers about the after life questions.

Comment: Than forget it but don't blame me if you got down-voted as said evidences don't explain themselves!